# crontab not running python script for Rpi.GPIO

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi2

I have a python script which I am trying to run at boot using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

using the following command

```
@reboot python /usr/local/sbin/ShutdownJumper.py
```

the script ShutdownJumper.py begins with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#note crontab for superuser required a new PATH variable as here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43392#answer-43394
import subprocess
try:
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except RuntimeError:
 print("Error importing RPi.GPIO! This is probably because you need superuser privileges. You can achieve this by using 'sudo' to run your script")
```

when I reboot my RPi I get the following email back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sbin/ShutdownJumper.py", line 4, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```

I've tried changing the [PATH in the crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43392/python-script-to-shutdown-system-doesnt-work-in-cron#answer-43394), so no avail..

Comment: what interpreter does `python` point to in your system? is `RPi` installed for that interpreter? is the path to `RPi` in your default `PYTHONPATH`? if not you could set `sys.path` to include the path to `RPi` in your python script.

Comment: Ok so /usr/bin/python links to /usr/bin/python2.7. If I run the script using sudo as user ubuntu, the script will run correctly. 
I haven't used paths in python before?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code on crontab

```
@reboot cd /usr/local/sbin && sudo python ShutdownJumper.py
```

Comment: works fine from the command line. Same error in my email:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ShutdownJumper.py", line 5, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO` 
:/